# Android dependencies side effect

Tags: android, dependencies

I am new in Android. My question is logical. Is there any side effect in using dependencies. For instance , i use

```
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
```

for viewpager.

Is this can be a problem in any way for me ?

Comment: You would need to be much more specific about the sort of "problem" that concerns you.

Comment: Are you having a problem with that particular dependency and asking if your declaration is the source?

Comment: Actually it is just example , i wonder is there Any side effect in using dependencies. For example , i can write my own classes for solve my issue in my application but i can compile some sources too for solve issue. Second option is easier and faster but using it is can be troublesome in any way ? sorry for bad english

Comment: there is no problem because you define your own classes in your own packages and directories. Even if a class has the same name, packages will be different (hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

No. A problem can be f you're using compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:+'
and then the author of the dependency changes something.
This may cause a problem because you will be using the latest version (because of '+' ) and will be never aware of the changes in the dependency.
As long as you specify the exact version you are safe.
There's a lint warning for that.